# JavaScript/CoffeeScript equivalent of Ruby Timeout module

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, settimeout

What would be the best way to realize the functionality of Ruby Timeout module in JavaScript?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

e.g. to cancel (async) requests which take longer to finish than a given time?

**EDIT:**

To make clear what I want to achieve:

For example if I do a HTTP request in node.js e.g.

```
http.request(options, callback).end();
```

And I want to cancel the request if it takes longer than a given timeout. So unbind the callback or everything what is need to make sure the request has no further effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel an (to) long running process create a 
variable that is accessible within the closure (function) you create with setTimeout

```
someLongRunningHttpRequest = new HttpRequest("point://some/where")

#cancel the request after 5 seconds
setTimeout -> 
    someLongRunningHttpRequest.cancel()
, 5000
```

obviously you need an object that is "cancable" or you could simple ignore the result?

Comment: how would it be possible to terminate all operations initialized inside a scope via a setTimeout?

Comment: I dont get your question - are you asking how to terminate the timeout function? that would be via clearTimeout(id_that_was_returned_via_setTimeout)

Comment: I mean if i start a request (db/http or something) and I want to terminate after the timeout no whether how the request has been implemented.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question then.
Its not clear what you are really asking then

Comment: updated my question. hope you get what I want to achieve now!